# How to delete a Column by comparing the Length of the Row?

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup

> Hello World, How to delete the entire column if the Length of  a particular Item is less than 5 or the Item is Empty ?
> This is how I am saving to CSV using pandas from a List :

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(Entertainmentlist)
df.to_csv('EnterTainment.csv', encoding='utf-8-sig' , index = False , mode = 'a')
```

> This is the screenshot of the CSV file :

[image]

> As you can see in the `Column 3` , the `heading is empty` or `has length <5`

> How can I loop for Entire CSV and delete the Complete column `including image and description` if heading is empty or length <5

Comment: Take care on `row vs col` - Please improve your question, so that we can reproduce your issue. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following, without delete any **row** just filter your `df`and then write it to `csv`

**Example**

```
import pandas as pd

cars = {'Brand': ['Honda Civic','Kia','Ford Focus','Audi A4'],
        'Price': [22000,25000,27000,35000]
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(cars, columns = ['Brand', 'Price'])
df_filtered = df[df['Brand'].map(len) > 5]

df_filtered.to_csv('cars.csv', encoding='utf-8-sig' , index = False , mode = 'a')
```

---

If you really wanna delete the **row** use `.drop()`

```
df.drop(df[df['Brand'].map(len) < 5].index, inplace=True)
```